# How to handle an exception in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, exception

am writing my first combat `Spring-MVC` project. There is a wallet in the customer’s class (`double` wallet field). The customer has the opportunity to withdraw money from the account. I would like to throw an error in the method if the user tries to withdraw more money than is available on the account. How to do this?

How can I get rid of the `if else` construct and process the method without them with `try catch`. Or is it better with `if`?

CustomerService:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.service;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomerService extends UserService {


    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }



    // Методы
    //

    public void withdrawMoney(Customer customer, double money){ 
        if (money <= customer.getWallet()) { // We make sure that the amount indicated by the customer is less than the wallet
            customer.setWallet(customer.getWallet() - money);
        } else {
            //////////!!!! OR TRY CATCH and how to implement?!!!!!!!!
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In order to get the try-catch work, you would need an exception(in the error case). This exception needs to be thrown by the `setWallet` method if the argument is smaller than zero.

Comment: Will setWallet throw it it's negative? Why not throw from the else block?

Comment: ..if the database 'd throw exception, then you are there.(without if,try/catch) but it is better practice to generally validate input parameters ("generally" better with `if` than with `try`), and to throw accordingly a customized or predefined (sort of) `IllegalArgumentException` ..and handle it.

Comment: in else block `throw new RuntimeException("insufficient funds in the account")` it's good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom Exception class e.g. OverWithDrawException
Register a Spring controller to handle the exception with HTTP status code

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

  // @RequestHandler methods
  ...

  // Exception handling methods

  // Convert a predefined exception to an HTTP Status code
  @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                  reason="Account over with draw attempt")  // 409
  @ExceptionHandler(OverWithDrawException.class)
  public void overWithDrawHandle() {
    // Nothing to do
  }

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", ex);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName("error");
    return mav;
  }

// Specify name of a specific view that will be used to display the error:
  @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
  public String databaseError() {
    // Nothing to do.  Returns the logical view name of an error page, passed
    // to the view-resolver(s) in usual way.
    // Note that the exception is NOT available to this view (it is not added
    // to the model) but see "Extending ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver"
    // below.
    return "databaseError";
  }

}
```

Copied above example from https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
I am pretty sure there will be newer and better ways to do it.

Comment: and then in the service in else{} call this method?

Comment: No. Once you register  controller with OverWithDrawException.class exception handling method Spring will automatically invoke overWithDrawHandle method whenever your code throws OverWithDrawException and the HTTP response will be returned from the overWithDrawHandle method itself.

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity, but how will my withdrawmoney method (code) be implemented?

Comment: Updated my ans to include more concrete method example you also anytime Spring doc mentioned in the ans.